# Vue component - entity multi select - is there any option to add a sorting feature?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, shopware, shopware6

I am using `<component name="sw-entity-multi-select">` and I am wondering if is there any option to add a drag-and-drop feature and make those selected values sortable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is an option using just the `xml` schema. You could consider to [create a custom component](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/administration/add-custom-component). In the template of the component you may then use `sw-entity-multi-select` with a property for the [`Criteria` object that includes sorting](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/administration/using-data-handling#working-with-the-criteria-class). In the same component you may also implement the desired drag'n'drop functionality yourself. Once you registered your custom component, you may then use it's name for the `name` attribute of the `component` tag.

```xml
<component name="my-custom-component">
```

Comment: That's what I thought. Thank you!